# OK button In dialog box

Tags: android

I am new in android , i have an issue with android UI. I want put OK button on the edge of the line in dialog  dialog. How can i do that.[image]

```
The xml i am using for now is this.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="defedfg" 
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button_xhdpi"
        android:text="@string/ok" 
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="#f7f6f5"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple solution. Give Take One Parent Layout and inside Take one LinearLayout and One button. Then Keep some margin on Layout Child

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="OK" />
```

And OutPut

[image]